# How can I get all children nested inside a View in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Just wondering if there was a quick way to do this before I write my own method: Trying to get the Checkboxes and Entries in this StackLayout "GarageOptionsLayout" programmatically so I can store certain values under certain conditions:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppName">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="GarageOptionsLayout">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Is There a Garage?"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       Margin="0,30,0,0"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="Large"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="GarageYesNoCheckBox" 
                          Margin="0,30,0,0"
                          CheckedChanged="GarageYesNoCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="AllOptionsLayout" IsVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                <Label Text="Construction"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           Margin="0,30,0,0"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="Large"
                    >
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                                Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
                <StackLayout x:Name="GarageConstructionGrid" 
                                 Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                 VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 IsVisible="False">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="TwoByFourConstructionCheckbox"/>
                    <Label Text="2x4" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <CheckBox  x:Name="TwoBySixContructionCheckbox"/>
                    <Label  Text="2x6" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="AdobeConstructionCheckbox"/>
                    <Label Text="Adobe" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="OtherGarageConstructionOptionCheckbox"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="GarageContructionEntry"
                               Placeholder="Other"
                               WidthRequest="100"
                               Margin="-10,0,10,0"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Interior Finish:"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Entry Placeholder="Please describe here" 
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               x:Name="InteriorFinishEntry"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Electric Opener:"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ElectricOpenerYesCheckbox"/>
                    <Label Text="Yes" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="-10,0,0,0"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ElectricOpenerNoCheckbox"/>
                    <Label Text="No" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="-10,0,0,0"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I'm really curious about whether or not there's a Xamarin Forms method that exists for this already, like View.FindType() or something. Anyway, I'm totally prepared to write my own method, just figured I'd ask.

Thanks!

Comment: use databinding, that will make this 1000x easier.  If you are manually trying to traverse the UI tree you are doing it the wrong way.

Comment: There is not any built-in method. Which could be considered a hint that that is not the recommended approach. As Jason said, use data binding. Or use the x:names you have.

Comment: use databinding + 1, you can get the value from viewmodel easily .

Comment: I haven't figured out how to use data binding to solve my overall problem. I want to save the state of a page when navigating away from it so everything doesn't just reset every time I navigate back. I was hoping I would be able to use data binding with a static class, but it requires a constructor to data bind every time a new page comes up. I've been trying to figure this out for days. Everyone keeps saying to use data binding. I really wish I knew how to get this done and I'm very surprised it's been so hard to figure it out. Thanks for any additional help you can provide

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, thanks